# get jquery plugin targeted object DOM

Tags: jquery, html, dom, plugins, target

to be honest I'm not sure how to technically ask about my current need, so I'll try show it using some pseudo code.

I'm building a jQuery plugin and I need to return 'targeted element's DOM' - something like this:

plugin usage:

`$('div.targeted-dom-element').myPlugin();`

and inside my plugin I want to return/reuse somewhere this 'div.targeted-dom-element' string (not object please!) - is there any jquery/js built-in function for such thing?

Comment: If you want NOT the object, then I assume you want the "selector"?

Comment: You should pass the selector string to the plugin, as per http://api.jquery.com/selector.

Comment: And why exactly would you need the string and not the resulting collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: this property is deprecated, thanks Matt for pointing this out.

jQuery objects has a `selector` property so you can do something like

```
myjQueryObj.selector
```

Comment: ["The `.selector` property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and is only maintained to the extent needed for supporting .live() in the jQuery Migrate plugin. It may be removed without notice in a future version. The property was never a reliable indicator of the selector that could be used to obtain the set of elements currently contained in the jQuery set where it was a property, since subsequent traversal methods may have changed the set. Plugins that need to use a selector should have the caller pass in the selector as part of the plugin's arguments during initialization."](http://goo.gl/L6YXgR)

Comment: yeah, I've seen that but it's weird because I've already used it with latest jquery and it works fine